# Shapefile Layer display filtering in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, filter, display

I use QGis 3.0, created several layers, each with multiple attributes.

I want to display only objects which have f.e. "123456789" as value in a specific attribute to print it and repeat with the next value.
It shouldn't just select the items but make everything else invisible.
I don't want to filter every singly layer. A filter which applies to every layer would be perfect since the attribute has the same name and value in every layer for the same order number.

The list might make thing a bit more clear:

The upper layer group "Trasseninhalte" are cables and pipes and connections.

The lower side "Trassenobjeckte und APL's" shows burrows to be made or already existing, usable pipes. "Knotenpunkte", "APL" are just connection points.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your layer-style with categories based on the values of that specific attribute. Turn all off but the one you need, then print, turn on the next and so on.[image]

You also could create a virtual layer which connects all your layers based upon your desired features ([see doc for QGis 3.0](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers)). You'd have to dive a bit into SQL, but this would be a rather simple query.

Comment: Can i make that work with multiple layers?
I do not want to make this a setting in every single one.

Comment: If the table schema is the same for the other layers after you set it for one save out a .qml style file and import that for the other layers.

Comment: to make this more exact:
the value is a order number. the order number is set as attribute in multiple layers. I want one filter to make all objects with that order number visible to make a price-calculation and create a excel sheet with the used materials.

you're technically correct, it would work but it is not as simple to use as i want it to be. If you have any other option i would be very grateful as i stilll am a beginner in gis-programs and don't know many functions of it

Comment: Why exactly do you have different layers?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope that helps explaining it.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Edited my answer, this should be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried some things and even though i browsed through the help and older stackexchange posts i did not manage to get the filter set up.
I don't know the needed function with which i can connect the layers.

I set up a link from other layers to the virtual one but couldn't get to filter it somehow.

Comment: Try this wiki/tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/. Also, your virtual layer should (as in "I hope so") combine all attribute tables of the layers you loaded into it. Then a simple "SELECT * FROM virtual-layer-name WHERE column-name=value" should suffice.